# How to encrypt user passwords for forum registrations?

Tags: mysql, encryption, passwords

What is the most secure way to encrypt user passwords for phpBB or MyBB forum registrations? I don't want anyone to be able to access the user passwords, not even those who administrate the MySQL database, and also if someone manages to hack the database to not be able to view them. I want only the users who register to know their passwords.

Comment: This is probably off-topic. However, since you seem to be using a 3d party application for your forum, you're probably stuck with whatever encryption it implements (if any). Typically passwords in a database are not encrypted but rather hashed with a one-way hash, such as MD5 or SHA. Encrypted passwords require you to also store the encryption/decryption key, which defeats the purpose of encryption.

Comment: DO NOT STORE PASSWORDS at all, ever, any time.  Store a hashed and salted version of the database that cannot be unencrypted.  When the user logs in, you hash+salt the password they entered at login, and compare the result with the stored version of the hash+salt.

Comment: Shouldn't you be hashing the password+salt?

Comment: that's actually what I meant, @Colin'tHart - the dangers of typing on my mobile, I suppose.

Comment: Or just me being pedantic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I completely agree with the response Federico Razzoli, except for one thing. Indeed, hashing must be performed upstream, in any case not at the database level (so your question is probably off topic).

**However simply using a hash function is not sufficient** in terms of security. You remain vulnerable to [dictionary attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack), [rainbow table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) attacks, and some attacks by frequency analysis. **It is essential** to at least use a [cryptographic salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29).

However, the best is to use a key derivation function designed to store passwords. I suggest you to look at [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) ([`hash_pbkdf2`](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.hash-pbkdf2.php) with PHP), [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) ([`password_hash`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) with PHP, which by default uses a judicious algorithm, bcrypt currently) or [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt).

Finally, your question suggests that you use phpBB, this forum engine should normally deal alone with the secure storage of passwords.

Comment: I'd suggest [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) rather than `hash_pbkdf2`.

Comment: @Calimo: By default, [`password_hash`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) uses bcrypt, so it’s a good choice indeed. Today most consider bcrypt is actually better than PBKDF2 (although both are just fine). I'll add a link. It may be interesting for the curious to take a look, even if it is fairly new, at the winner of [Password Hashing Competition](https://password-hashing.net/): [Argon2](https://password-hashing.net/submissions/specs/Argon-v3.pdf) (Argon2i version for password-based key derivation).

Comment: the good thing with `password_hash`/`password_verify` is that transition to better/safer algorithms will be totally transparent when PHP decides to do so, nothing to re-code, no (or not much) unsafe code left behind.

Comment: @Calimo Yes, that's a good point, I added a remark about this in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SHA512.

I see that you used the "mysql" tag. Please, don't use the `SHA2()` SQL function, or any other SQL hash function. If you do so, the plain strings will be sent across the net, and probably written in some logs.

Use the PHP `hash()` function instead, and specify `'sha256'` as first parameter.